# understanding jquery with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

My `js` file `forms.js` looks as shown below.
This file is called using `requirejs` from some other `js` file.

Does the code written in `function(){}` run even if the required `js` files are already present in `head`?

If No, then is there a way to run it?

```
var scriptpath = Core.path;
require([scriptpath + "jquery-datepicker.min.js"], function(){
      //some code goes here
});
```

Comment: Why not set a debugger breakpoint inside to check it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The code will run even if the file is already included in the `head`. But the question is the following :

Why do you include the file in the `head` if you are using `requirejs` ? The `requirejs` job is to find the file for you.

Comment: Because the form.js called for every onclick of a button, on subsequent onclick it doesnt function the way it is supposed to. i.e the datepicker doesnt work.